# Function call missing required positional argument:

Tags: python, python-3.x, variables, scope

I'm making a restaurant tab program for class and the teacher asked us to 'modularize' it from the original. However, I keep getting the error"

> TypeError: computeTotal() missing 1 required positional argument: 'drinks')

I know it's a scope error but I'm not sure how to fix it since the variable is a global variable.

```
def getdrinks():
    drinks = float(input('dollar amount for drinks: $'))
    return drinks

def getapps():
    apps = float(input('dollar amount for apps: $'))
    return apps

def getMC():
    mainCourse = float(input('dollar amount for main course: $'))
    return mainCourse

def getdessert():
    dessert = float(input('dollar amount for desserts: $'))
    return dessert

def getPurchaseAmts():
    getdrinks()
    getapps()
    getMC()
    getdessert()
getPurchaseAmts()

def computeTotal(drinks, apps, mainCourse, dessert):
    Total = (drinks + apps + mainCourse + dessert)
    print ("Bill total (before tax and preTip): ",Total)
computeTotal()    

drinks = getdrinks()
apps = getapps()
mainCourse = getMC()
dessert = getdessert()
```

Comment: Please do not post images of code (or, worse, links to images). [edit] the question and copy-and-paste the code into it. Also, tag a language: [tag:python].

Comment: I have changed it, I apologize.

Comment: How many parameters did you define for your method `def computeTotal`? How many did you give `computeTotal()`? Now, read your error again, please. And it has nothing to do with scope

Answer (score 0):

You're confusing parameters with externally defined values.

Those parameters could be named completely different things, and even though they are currently the same as the others, that does not mean that their values are automatically passed into the function

For example,

```
def computeTotal(a, b, c, d):
    total = (a + b + c + d)
    print ("Bill total (before tax and preTip): ",total)


drinks = getdrinks()
apps = getapps()
mainCourse = getMC()
dessert = getdessert()

# this must be last, and you need to pass values into the function 
computeTotal(drinks, apps, mainCourse, dessert)
```

And you can remove `getPurchaseAmts()` because it's not doing anything but making you repeat your inputs twice